# how to use selenium from Google Cloud Platform AI notebook?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver

I run code below,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument(
            f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'
            )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

but, I get the error below

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_19299/2976345773.py in <module>
     12             f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'
     13             )
---> 14 driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
     15 # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     16 driver.get("http://www.python.org")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     70         super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
     71                                         port, options,
---> 72                                         service_args, desired_capabilities,
     73                                         service_log_path, service, keep_alive)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py in __init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
     87             raise AttributeError('service cannot be None')
     88 
---> 89         self.service = service
     90         self.service.start()
     91 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     96         count = 0
     97         while True:
---> 98             self.assert_process_still_running()
     99             if self.is_connectable():
    100                 break

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
    110             raise WebDriverException(
    111                 'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
--> 112                 % (self.path, return_code)
    113             )
    114 

WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/jupyter/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Would you teach How can I use selenium from Google Cloud Platform AI notebook?
I tried installing chromedriver and headless-chromium from the terminal, but I can't solve it.Thank you.